# I want to move items with jquery but html structure is conflicting on ie8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I need help; If last Menu in first column bigger size than all li items in second column; I want to move last Menu in first column to top of second column then remove the cloned menu.

It is working on chrome but not working on ie8. What is the solution? If you have better idea for this work, please tell me..

Thanks..

```
<style>
        .col3 { width:33.33333333333333%; float:left; }
</style>
$(document).ready(function () {
        col1="<div class=\"col3\"><ul><li><h3>Menu1</h3></li><li>Child1</li></ul><ul><li><h3>Menu2</h3></li><li>Child1</li><li>Child2</li><li>Child3</li><li>Child4</li><li>Child5</li></ul></div>"
        col2="<div class=\"col3\"><ul><li><h3>Menu3</h3></li><li>Child1</li><li>Child2</li><li>Child3</li><li>Child3</li></ul></div>"
        tmp=col1+col2;

        a1 = $(tmp)[0].innerHTML;
        a2 = $(tmp)[0];         
        var LastUl = $(a2).children('ul:last-child')[0].outerHTML;      
        var LastLiSize = $(LastUl).children('li').size();

        var b1 = $(tmp)[1].innerHTML;
        var b2 = $(tmp)[1];     
        col2LiSize = $(b1).children('li').size();

        if (LastLiSize > col2LiSize) {
            var lastUl = a1.lastIndexOf("<ul>");
            var clone = a1.substring(lastUl);
            var col1tmp = a1.replace(clone, "");
            var col2tmp = $(col2);
            col2tmp.prepend($(clone));

            result=' <div class=\"col3\">' + col1tmp + '</div> <div class=\"col3\">' + $(col2tmp).html() + '</div>';

            $('body').append('<div style=\"clear:both;\">'+result+'</div>');
        }
        else {
            $('body').append('<div style=\"clear:both;\">'+tmp+'</div>');
        }
        });
```

Comment: What exactly is not working on IE8? Are you perchance using the 2.0 branch of jQuery?

Comment: I don't see the use of `.clone()` or `.remove()` in your code. All I see is a variable named `clone`. Care to elaborate?

Comment: HTML structure has been conflict on IE8. jQuery version is 1.10.2 @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: I'm replacing with "" which need to remove. @War10ck

Comment: sounds like you're copying or changing content. In either case, you are not using `.clone()` or `.remove()`. Make sure you don't confuse native JavaScript with jQuery functionality.